# ASP.NET CORE Razor Pages: How to avoid executing page handler 2nd time on page refresh?

Tags: asp.net-core, methods, handler, razor-pages

When using method handlers to execute `OnGet` or `OnPost` methods, `&handler=[action]` query string gets added.

Problem is if user manually refreshes the page afterwards by hitting browser's refresh button, the same action will get executed for the 2nd time unintentionally.

**What is the recommended approach to avoid this?**

Answer (score 1):

> Problem is if user manually refreshes the page afterwards, same action
> will get executed for the 2nd time.

For the browser refresh button click event, we can't prevent it. But, as a workaround, you could defined a TriggerCount property in the page model, and use a hidden field to store the value in the form, then in the handler method, get the hidden field value and based on the count to do something. Code as below:

code in the .cshtml.cs page:

```
    public void OnPostDelete()
    {
        if (Request.Form["TriggerCount"].Count > 0)
        {
            TriggerCount = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["TriggerCount"]);
            TriggerCount++;
        }
        if (TriggerCount < 2)
        {
            // do something.
            Message = "Delete handler fired, Count:" + TriggerCount;
        }
        else
        {
            Message = "Over 2 times";
        }
    }
```

Code in the .cshtml page:

```
@page
@model RazorPageSample.Pages.HandlerPageModel
@{
}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <form asp-page-handler="edit" method="post">
            <button class="btn btn-default">Edit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <form asp-page-handler="delete" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="TriggerCount" /> 
            <button id="btndelete" disabled="@(Model.TriggerCount>=1?true:false)"  class="btn btn-default">
                Delete
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<h3 class="clearfix">@Model.Message</h3>
```

the screenshot as below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for a very detailed answer. I actually was looking for a way to prevent triggering same action on browser refresh (ie: Chromes refresh button). Basically, after hitting button for 1st time, if user manually refreshes the page same method handler will be executed unintentionally, I'd like to prevent that.

Comment: OK, I understand. For the browser refresh button click event, we can't prevent it. But, I found that using above code, if we refresh the page by click the browser refresh button, it will not submit the form, so the TriggerCount (using my previous code) value will keep `1`, when you click the Delete button again, the TriggerCount value will + 1, you could use this method to check whether the page is refreshed via the browser click event or not. You can consider using it as a workaround.